# Could there be a way to escape this loop?(problem with fade and leds)

Tags: loops, arduino, fade, led

```
int led1 = 3;
int led2 = 5;
int led3 = 6;
int led4 = 9;
int m = 1;
int brightness = 10;
int fadeAmount = 5;
int led;
int one = 1;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (m == 4 or m == 1) {
    one = -one;
  }
  if (intensite <= 5){
      m = m + one;
    }
  if (m == 1) {
    led = led1;
  }
  if (m == 2) {
    led = led2;
  }
  if (m == 3) {
    led = led3;
  }
  if (m == 4) {
    led = led4;
  }
  

    brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

   if (brightness <= 5 or brightness >= 255) {
     fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
   }
   analogWrite(led,brightness);
   delay(10);
}
```

When I run this part of the code, it just gets stuck in a infinite loop at the top led and it does not go back down the way it should which I fail to see. It would be of great help if one could help me understand my mistake. The aim is to make a code that lights leds from right to left (led1 to led4) then left to right (led4 to led1), not simply turning them on but fading them.

Comment: Please give more details. The info that you provided is not enough, you named variables terribly and didn't even explained your code or expected behavior...

Comment: sorry for the variable I'm French so for me they're simple, I'll translate them

Comment: @loloToster I hope the edits makes it easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my best to stay as close to your code as possible. So your code didn't work because it don't make much sense. Why would you make this `one` variable? It just complicated all the things. Just put a `boolean` which indicates whether you are going left or not and change it based on the current value of `m`. Here is how:

```cpp
int led1 = 3;
int led2 = 5;
int led3 = 6;
int led4 = 9;
int m = 1;
int brightness = 10;
int fadeAmount = 5;
int led;
bool goingLeft;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (m == 1) { // If we are on the right side we set goingLeft to true
    goingLeft = true;
  }else if(m == 4){ // If we are on the left side we set goingLeft to false
    goingLeft = false;
  }
  if (brightness <= 5 && goingLeft){ // if we are moving left then we increment the m variable
      m++;
  }else if(brightness <= 5){ // if we are moving right we decrement it
    m--;
  }
  if (m == 1) {
    led = led1;
  }
  if (m == 2) {
    led = led2;
  }
  if (m == 3) {
    led = led3;
  }
  if (m == 4) {
    led = led4;
  }
    brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;

   if (brightness <= 5 or brightness >= 255) {
     fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
   }
   analogWrite(led,brightness);
   delay(10);
}
```

If I were you I would do this in a completly diffrent way by using `for` loops but as I said earlier I tried to stay as close to your code as I could.

**Also** I saw that you used `or` in your code. Don't do it!!! In C languages the or operator is `||` not `or`

Comment: helps a lot. Do you have a keyboard shortcut to do the || symbol ?

Comment: It is probably Shift + (The key over Enter) on your keyboard.